# Как сделать обтекание блока слева?

Tags: html, css

Сделал общий div для секции с width 100%.

Вставил в него картинку с картой, поставил картинке с картой width 50% и float: right.

Все ок.

Вопрос: как сделать левый блок что бы он обтекал слева но не до самого левого края страницы, и чтобы не лезло никуда при масштабировании?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сижу ломаю голову и запутался уже ребята, помогите

Answer (score 0):

должен быть еще один div, с отступом X слева и справа, а аж потом в него впихивать другие div-ы. Даже этот сайт - stackoverflow использует такой стиль. слева и справа пустые поля как видишь.